# Python: Can I partially apply reduce with an initializer?

Tags: python, functional-programming, reduce, partial-application, functools

The `initializer` comes after the `iterable`. This causes problems for partial application. Consider these (trivial) examples:

```
In [1]: from functools import reduce, partial

In [2]: f = partial(reduce, lambda a,b: a+b, 100)

In [3]: f([1,2,3])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-816cce84b257> in <module>()
----> 1 f([1,2,3])

TypeError: reduce() arg 2 must support iteration

In [4]: f = partial(reduce, lambda a,b: a+b, initializer=100)

In [5]: f([1,2,3])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-816cce84b257> in <module>()
----> 1 f([1,2,3])

TypeError: reduce() takes no keyword arguments
```

Is there some trick to get around this?

Comment: The problem seems to be the commas _inside_ your lambda. Try parenthesizing the whole thing.

Comment: The problem is the order of the arguments.

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't use `reduce` a ton, so I didn't remember the order off the top of my head.

Comment: Why not append 100 to your input list?

Comment: this was just a trivial example of the pattern. That wouldn't work in all situations.

Comment: So do you have an actual example, where the only option is to pass an initializer to reduce?

Comment: ...are you asking why reduce has an initializer?

Comment: I guess so! Since this is the title of your question.

Comment: Well, in Python the main case is if its possible the list is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the order of arguments:

```
>>> f = partial(lambda func, init, iterable: reduce(func, iterable, init), 
                lambda a,b: a+b, 100)
>>> f([1,2,3])
106
```

Comment: Cool solution!!

Answer (score 0):

Marat gave a great solution. For fun, I wrote `foldl` with the arguments flipped. I'm curious how this would compare performance-wise to using a lambda to flip the arguments like Marat did.

```
def foldl(f: Callable, acc: Any, xs: Iterable) -> Any:
    if not xs:
        return acc
    return foldl(f, f(acc, xs[0]), xs[1:])
```